# Alumnos registrados en un proyecto

Tags: php, mysql

En mi sistema tengo la capacidad de registrar a través de checkbox alumnos a un proyecto, y quitarlo de el, ocurre que no he podido limitar a que los alumnos solo puedan pertenecer a un solo proyecto.

Al momento de inscribirlos aparecen todos y la persona puede seleccionarlos para otro proyecto como podría arreglar eso?.

ademas de que el listado de los alumnos inscritos muestra datos de la tabla proyecto y de la tabla proyecto_alumnos, pero al borrar a todos los alumnos queda un registro con los datos del proyecto y no se puede borrar. aquí los códigos:

Formulario de inscripción de alumnos

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Change es un evento que se ejecuta cada vez que se cambia el valor de un elemento (input, select, etc).
    $('#proyectos').change(function(e) {
      $('#proy_id').val($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>

<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$alumno = bd_alumno_opciones();
$proyecto = bd_proyecto_opciones();
include 'cab.php';
?>

<div>
    <center>
        <h1> Inscripción de Alumnos </h1>
        <font size=3 color="red">*</font> <font size =3>Campos Obligatorios</font>
    </center>
</div>

<form id="frmIns" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="proc_modif_alumno_inscrito.php" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="proyectos" class="control-label col-lg-2"><font size=3 color="red">*</font>Proyecto:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <select class="form-control" name="proyecto" id="proyectos">

        <?php foreach($proyecto as $i=>$proyecto_temp):?>

            <option value="<?=$i?>"><?=$proyecto_temp?></option>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">

        <input type="hidden" name="proy_id" id="proy_id" readonly  value="" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="alumno" class="col-lg-2 control-label"><font size=3 color="red">*</font>Alumnos:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">

        <?php foreach($alumno as $i=>$alumno_temp): ?>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="alum[]" id="alum_<?=$i?>" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$alumno_temp?>
            </label>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Guardar</button>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Al guardar pasa a este: PROC_INSCRIPCION 4

```
<?php include 'conexion.php';

      print_r($_REQUEST); 

      foreach ($_REQUEST['alum'] as $alumno_id) {

          $alumno = array(

              'proy_id' => NULL, 
              'proy_id' => $_REQUEST['proy_id'], 
              'alum_id' => $alumno_id);   

          bd_proyecto_alumno_agregar($alumno); 
       } 

       header("Location: listado4.php"); 
       exit;
```

Para modificar los que están en la lista:

```
    <?php include 'conexion.php'; 

          bd_proyecto_alumno_modificar($_REQUEST['proy_id']);

          foreach ($_REQUEST['alum'] as $alumno_id){

              $alumno = array(

                 'proy_alum_id' => NULL, 
                 'proy_id' => $_REQUEST['proy_id'], 
                 'alum_id' => $alumno_id); 

                  bd_proyecto_alumno_agregar($alumno);

              }

              header("Location: listado4.php"); 
              exit; 



function bd_proyecto_alumno_modificar($d)
{

    $proy_deno=$_REQUEST['proy_deno'];

    $sql = sprintf("UPDATE proyecto 
                    SET proy_deno = '$proy_deno'            
                    where proy_id='$d'");

    $res=sql($sql);

    $sql="DELETE FROM proyecto_alumno WHERE proy_id = '$d'";

    $res=sql($sql);
    return $d;         
}


function bd_proyecto_alumno_agregar($d)
{
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO 
                    proyecto_alumno (proy_alum_id, proy_id, alum_id) 
                    VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')",

                    $d['proy_requ_id'],
                    $d['proy_id'],
                    $d['alum_id']);

    $res = sql($sql);
    $id  = sql2value("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
    return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen día, en lo que corresponde a que un alumno solo puede estar en un proyecto se puede arreglar poniendo el *alumn_id* como campo único en la tabla *proyecto_alumno*, de esta manera no se podrá repetir y solo podrá cambiar de proyecto si primero se da de baja del actual.

En lo que corresponde a obtener solo a los alumnos que no tengan proyecto el sql a usar sería:

```
SELECT cedu_alum, CONCAT(cedu_alum,' ',nom1_alum,' ',nom2_alum,' ',ape1_alum,' ',ape2_alum)
FROM alumno LEFT JOIN proyecto_alumno ON cedu_alum = alum_id 
WHERE proy_id = null ORDER BY cedu_alum ASC
```

El **LEFT JOIN** da prioridad a la tabla de la izquierda (en este caso alumno) por tanto nos trae los datos de esa tabla alumno y le agrega los datos de *proyecto_alumno* siempre y cuando coincidan a lo establecido en **ON cedu_alum = alum_id** esto quiere decir que si se encuentra la cedula del alumno en la tabla *proyecto_alumno* se agrega en que proyecto está a la consulta, y si no se encuentra no le agrega nada (null) ya al final usamos el **WHERE** para indicar que solo nos entregue los que no tengan un proyecto asignado.

Comment: function bd_alumno_opciones()
{
   $sql = "SELECT cedu_alum, CONCAT(cedu_alum,' ',nom1_alum,' ',nom2_alum,' ',ape1_alum,' ',ape2_alum) FROM alumno ORDER BY cedu_alum ASC";
   $res = sql2options( $sql );
return $res;
}

Comment: DISCULPA la tardanza ando un poco ocupado

Comment: Victor, hice cambios para que le des una chacada, y sobre lo que preguntas en el párrafo 3,  podrías ser más claro en que función ocurre ese error?